# openmp dependency on successive vector elements

Tags: dependencies, openmp

I want to parallelize the following algorithm using OpenMP. 
A and C are the input data and B is the output.
A is a vector and the element A[i] shows the number of elements in the i-th row of the array C.
Is the parallelization possible;

```
bno=0;
for (j=0; j<A[0]; j++)
    B[bno++] = C[0][j];

for (i=1; i<L; i++) 
    for (j=0; j<A[i]; j++)
        for (k=0; k<A[i-1]; k++) 
            if ( f(C[i][j], C[i-1][k]) == 1) 
                B[bno++]=C[i][j];
```

Comment: not parallelizable in straightforward manner except by altering the storage locations in B[], possibly packing afterwards to recover the original layout.

Comment: A practical answer requires a [mcve] and also what language this.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite a minimal, complete and verifiable version of the serial code in C. 
About the variables: The table A[N][M] of integers is input to my code, the vector B[] of integers is output and the integer bno is output and stores the number of integers that copied in vector B[].
Is this serial serial code parallelizable? I use OpenMP.

```
bno=0;
for (i=1; i<N; i++) 
    for (j=0; j<M; j++)
        for (k=0; k<M; k++) 
            if ( C[i][j] == C[i-1][k] ) 
                B[bno++]=C[i][j];
```

For example for the following input:
A[4][3]=[
7, 8, 9,
1, 2, 8
0, 5, 6
6, 6, 5]
the output should be:  B=[8, 6, 6, 5], bno=4.